# Meteor server code forEach statement no longer works

Tags: mongodb, foreach, meteor

I have the following server side code in Meteor, which used to work fine. Now, for some reason, the cursor.forEach(callback) function no longer seems to work.

```
//// SERVER SIDE CODE
Meteor.startup(function () {    
FlickrUserID(apiKey,userName,function(){
    FlickrSetList(apiKey,userID,flickrDB,flickrDBKey,function(){
        var setList = flickrDB.find({name:flickrDBKey});
        setList.forEach(function(eachSetItem){
            var flickrSetID=eachSetItem.data.id;
            FlickrSetPhotos(apiKey,flickrSetID,flickrDBKey);
        });
        Meteor.publish("sets",function(){
            return flickrDB.find(
                {},
                {fields: {id:1,data:1,photos:1}}
            );
        });
    });
});
});
```

All the functions and the database appear to be working, but for some reason the function inside the setList.forEach function no longer gets triggered. I've tried the function outside the forEach and it works fine, so it appears to be something with the actual forEach function.

I'm stumped and have spent much time trying to figure out where I've gone wrong...is there a typo that I've somehow introduced? Or is there something deeper or elsewhere that may be affecting whether or not the forEach function can run?

Comment: Could you check for item named flickrDBKey is actually stored in your database? What happens if you add console.log(flickrDB.find({name:flickrDBKey}).fetch()) right after setList variable assignment?

Comment: @4pcbr - This turns out to be a case of "operator error"! Your suspicions got me going in the right direction - I discovered that I've been looking for the "name" field and somewhere along the line I had changed the title of this field to "key" in the function where I upsert the database... Thanks for your help.

Comment: @4pcbr - PS - when I run the console log I get an empty object using the "name" field but get all objects returned using the "key" field instead.

Comment: glad to hear you've solved it)